# switch case in Yii2 activeQuery

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

Can we have a ***Switch Case Query*** in more Yii2 ActiveQuery way than core SQL below ?

```
$comboGraph = \Yii::$app->db->createCommand('select class , count(*) registered, '.
    'sum(case when payment_status = \'1\' then 1 else 0 end) paid, '.
    'sum(case when payment_status = \'0\' then 1 else 0 end) unpaid '.
    'from students group by class ORDER BY FIELD(class,\'V\',\'VI\',\'VII\')')
    ->queryAll();
```

I am getting results even if I use above query, but I want my stuff to be more Yii2 Specific. So any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

The use of createCommand is  Yii2 complaint .. (and at the moment there are not specific function for manage CASE WHEN .. statements, these  statementes are managed  by flat sql instruction )

But could be you want use  the query builder and the related  function  .. 
  http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-query-builder.html

```
$comboGraph = (new \yii\db\Query())
->select("class 
        , count(*) registered
        , sum(case when payment_status = '1' then 1 else 0 end) paid
        , sum(case when payment_status = '0' then 1 else 0 end) unpaid")
->from('students')
->groupBy('class')
->orderBy("FIELD(class,'V','VI','VII')")
->all();
```

*You can use a proper combination of single and double quote for a better reading*